# In OSX with oh-my-zsh installed, how to highlight the output of `ls` in oh-my-zsh with Solarized theme installed

Tags: macos, ls, oh-my-zsh

I recently configured my terminal according to [this blog](http://www.drbunsen.org/the-text-triumvirate/). After followed it step by step, everything is OK but the colour of `ls`'s outputs are grey.

I googled this problem and found [this](https://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized/issues/10). It says that adding `export LSCOLORS=gxfxbEaEBxxEhEhBaDaCaD` to the `.bash_profile` will resolve this problem.

BUT, I use `zsh` with `oh-my-zsh` instead of `bash`. There is no `bash_profile` at `~`. I also tried to add this environments variable to `.zshrc`, it didn't work unfortunately.

Another way to resolve this problem is to install `coreutils` packets and use GNU `ls` instead. However, I reluctantly to install this big packets just for a `ls` command.

How can I fix this problem.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally surrendered to install `GNU-ls` instead...